# how do we determine the 'real' type of a user defined type?

Tags: c

I'm getting back into programming in C. I haven't done anything in linux before now, and my previous coding was done in DOS with Borland 3.1 -- so I have a lot of catching up to do! I'm playing with the 'codelite' IDE since it seems well spoken of. So far, nothing but trouble, but I'm muddling through. At this point I'm stuck looking at:

```
{
    Display *display;
    int x;
    ...
```

How does one determine what type 'Display' is? In good old Borland, you move the cursor over the type, and hit F1 and it tells you :-) I want to fprint the value of 'display' but have no clue what format specifier to use.

Oh, and any general advice anyone might have for a guy like me, just now jumping from C coding in DOS to Linux will be warmly received!

Comment: It depends on which IDE you're using!  If you're just using a basic text editor, you'll simply have to trace back through the definitions in the header files.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the codelite IDE - if it has this option, it would be easiest.
The hard way is to dig through the header files.
Another way would be to compile your code with the -E flag, which just opens up includes and defines. In the (very large) output you'd get, look for Display and see how it's defined.

Comment: I suggest `gcc -C -E` because the comments also help to understand where is the line coming from.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, you mean typing a command like `gcc -C -E myfile.c | less`, using (together with `-C -E`) all the other options that one would normally use to compile myfile.c. Nice idea.

Comment: I tried the CLI method just above, and I still couldn't find the typedef :(

Comment: Then it is missing, and some more `#include` of other files is needed.

Answer (score 3):

If using the `gdb` debugger (assuming you compile with `gcc -Wall -g` as you always should) you can also use the `ptype Display` command inside `gdb`.

And your use of `Display`  makes me guess that you are interested in graphical user interface (since `Display` is an `Xlib` thing). Then I strongly suggest using a powerful GUI toolkit library like e.g. *GTK3* (in C) or *Qt4.8* (in C++). Don't use Xlib directly; you'll be lost!

For console applications where you need a real terminal, consider using `ncurses` or `readline` libraries.

You don't need an IDE to code under Linux (`emacs` + `make` + `gdb` + `gcc` + `grep` + `etags` are fine). Use `gcc -Wall -g` to compile your C code, and correct it until you got no more warnings. Use, even for personal projects, a version control system like `git`.

Take advantage that Linux is **free software** so study and improve all the source code you want.

And of course, learn about the role of the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), the importance of [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). Look into [intro(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/intro) and [syscalls(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) man pages (and learn to use the `man`).

Don't forget the complexity of [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)-s (i.e. terminals).

Comment: Or at least use xcb, it's a modern replacement for xlib.

Comment: I won't recommend xcb for a Linux beginner. I would recommend GTK or Qt instead. X11 protocol and related specifications (ICCCM etc...) are very complex.

Comment: Well, "at least", as in: "even if you think you have to use low-level X11 protocol, at least use a modern library for that". I also think GTK/Qt are better choice.

Comment: I haven't used gdb yet, but I'll play with it. There seems to be lots of advice to use CLI tools rather than an IDE, but for now that's what I'm comfortable with ... but I'll keep tinkering. FWIW 'gcc-Wall -g -lX11 filename' followed by 'gdb exename' gives me: "(no dubugging symbols found)

Comment: You should *compile* with `gcc -Wall -g myprog.c -lX11 -o myprog` then *debug* with `gdb myprog` but again, X11 is very complex in the details, so better use a toolkit like *Gtk*

Comment: Basile, I've got gdb working but 'ptype Display' doesn't work. When I man gdb 'ptype' is not found. As to different libraries is there somewhere I can find a tutorial on converting from one to the other? Like which functions to use in place of which?

Comment: `ptype Display` is a command to type inside `gdb`; it is not a shell command.

Comment: Regarding choice of graphical toolkit libraries; it is a matter of look & feel (e.g. Gnome vs KDE), it is a matter of language (C vs C++), and it is a matter of taste. You have to choose one to start with. If you like coding in *C*, choose *Gtk*. The concepts you will learn will be useful even when you'll want to learn *Qt*. And there exist also several other minor graphical toolkit libraries (FLTK, Fox, ...)

Comment: Basile, Ok, I'm inside gdm but I can't enter a space after 'ptype' so I end up with 'ptypeDisplay'. That seems very strange. I have found a tutorial that says exactly what you say, but why can't I space? .... AH, I must use the TAB :-( .... who's idea is that?